# Проблема с калькулятором расчета стоимости

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток друзья! Есть некий калькулятор для сайта клининга с калькулятором подробным, проблема заключается в том что когда меняю курс валюты то калькулятор перестает работать. Тут какое-то правило стоит чтобы символы былий английскими и только из трех букв (Типа как RUB, BYN, USD) а как только пишу русскими например "рублей" то калькулятор тут же перестает работать... Я бы вставил сюда код но он очень длинный но все же попробую.

Вот ссылка на мой калькулятор https://cleanking.kz/order.html

В самом HTML файле калькулятора вот так:

```
data-type="default"
             
                data-customer-subscription="0"
             
             data-token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZWNyZXRfa2V5IjoiYzQ3NTMyOTZmY2FmODE0Y2EwZGM3MTIzOGVkMjQ5YjciLCJmb3JtIjoiZm9ybS1hZGQtb3JkZXIiLCJkYXRhIjp7fSwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNjIzNTc4MDI1LCJpYXQiOjE2MjM1NzgwMjV9.NzbvhAvuVya_-kryHiVIFTa2CjRULf4adaHeLMggTOU"
             data-validate-price="true"
             data-currency-code="RUB"
             data-currency-precision="0"
             data-rooms=""
             data-bathrooms=""
             data-periodicity="">
```

А в файле JS вот:

```
'use strict';
var Defaults = {
        defaultAmount: 0,
        defaultCurrency: 'USD',
        defaultPrecision: 2
    },
    Globals = {
        globalLocale: 'en-US',
        globalFormat: '$0,0.00',
        globalRoundingMode: 'HALF_EVEN',
        globalFormatRoundingMode: 'HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO',
        globalExchangeRatesApi: {
            endpoint: void 0,
            headers: void 0,
            propertyPath: void 0
        }
    },
    Static = {
        normalizePrecision: function (a) {
            var b = a.reduce(function (c, a) {
                return Math.max(c.getPrecision(), a.getPrecision())
            });
            return a.map(function (a) {
                return a.getPrecision() === b ? a : a.convertPrecision(b)
            })
        }
    },
    _typeof = 'function' == typeof Symbol && 'symbol' == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function (a) {
        return typeof a
    } : function (a) {
        return a && 'function' == typeof Symbol && a.constructor === Symbol && a !== Symbol.prototype ? 'symbol' : typeof a
    };

function isNumeric(a) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(a)) && isFinite(a)
}

function isPercentage(a) {
    return isNumeric(a) && 100 >= a && 0 <= a
}

function areValidRatios(a) {
    return 0 < a.length && a.every(function (a) {
        return 0 < a
    })
}

function isEven(a) {
    return 0 == a % 2
}

function isFloat(a) {
    return isNumeric(a) && !Number.isInteger(a)
}

function countFractionDigits() {
    var a = 0 < arguments.length && arguments[0] !== void 0 ? arguments[0] : 0,
        b = a.toString().split('.')[1];
    return b ? b.length : 0
}

function isHalf(a) {
    return .5 == Math.abs(a) % 1
}

function getJSON(a) {
    var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : {};
    return new Promise(function (c, d) {
        var e = Object.assign(new XMLHttpRequest, {
            onreadystatechange: function () {
                4 === e.readyState && (200 <= e.status && 400 > e.status ? c(JSON.parse(e.responseText)) : d(new Error(e.statusText)))
            },
            onerror: function () {
                d(new Error('Network error'))
            }
        });
        e.open('GET', a, !0), setXHRHeaders(e, b.headers), e.send()
    })
}

function setXHRHeaders(a) {
    var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : {};
    for (var c in b) a.setRequestHeader(c, b[c]);
    return a
}

function isUndefined(a) {
    return 'undefined' == typeof a
}

function flattenObject(a) {
    var b = 1 < arguments.length && void 0 !== arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : '.',
        c = {};
    return Object.entries(a).forEach(function (a) {
        if ('object' === _typeof(a[1])) {
            var d = flattenObject(a[1]);
            Object.entries(d).forEach(function (d) {
                c[a[0] + b + d[0]] = d[1]
            })
        } else c[a[0]] = a[1]
    }), c
}

function isThenable(a) {
    return !!a && ('object' === ('undefined' == typeof a ? 'undefined' : _typeof(a)) || 'function' == typeof a) && 'function' == typeof a.then
}

function Calculator() {
    var a = Math.sign,
        b = Math.floor,
        c = Math.round,
        d = Math.abs,
        e = function (d, a) {
            var b = function (a) {
                    return Math.pow(10, countFractionDigits(a))
                },
                e = Math.max(b(d), b(a));
            return c(d * e) * c(a * e) / (e * e)
        },
        f = {
            HALF_ODD: function (a) {
                var b = c(a);
                return isHalf(a) ? isEven(b) ? b - 1 : b : b
            },
            HALF_EVEN: function (a) {
                var b = c(a);
                return isHalf(a) ? isEven(b) ? b : b - 1 : b
            },
            HALF_UP: function (a) {
                return c(a)
            },
            HALF_DOWN: function (a) {
                return isHalf(a) ? b(a) : c(a)
            },
            HALF_TOWARDS_ZERO: function (e) {
                return isHalf(e) ? a(e) * b(d(e)) : c(e)
            },
            HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO: function (b) {
                return isHalf(b) ? a(b) * Math.ceil(d(b)) : c(b)
            }
        };
    return {
        add: function (c, a) {
            return c + a
        },
        subtract: function (c, a) {
            return c - a
        },
        multiply: function (c, a) {
            return isFloat(c) || isFloat(a) ? e(c, a) : c * a
        },
        divide: function (c, a) {
            return c / a
        },
        modulo: function (c, a) {
            return c % a
        },
        round: function (a) {
            var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : 'HALF_EVEN';
            return f[b](a)
        }
    }
}
var calculator = Calculator();

function Format(a) {
    var b = /^(?:(\$|USD)?0(?:(,)0)?(\.)?(0+)?|0(?:(,)0)?(\.)?(0+)?\s?(dollar)?)$/gm.exec(a);
    return {
        getMatches: function () {
            return null === b ? [] : b.slice(1).filter(function (a) {
                return !isUndefined(a)
            })
        },
        getMinimumFractionDigits: function () {
            var a = function (a) {
                return '.' === a
            };
            return isUndefined(this.getMatches().find(a)) ? 0 : this.getMatches()[calculator.add(this.getMatches().findIndex(a), 1)].split('').length
        },
        getCurrencyDisplay: function () {
            return {
                USD: 'code',
                dollar: 'name',
                $: 'symbol'
            } [this.getMatches().find(function (a) {
                return 'USD' === a || 'dollar' === a || '$' === a
            })]
        },
        getStyle: function () {
            return isUndefined(this.getCurrencyDisplay(this.getMatches())) ? 'decimal' : 'currency'
        },
        getUseGrouping: function () {
            return !isUndefined(this.getMatches().find(function (a) {
                return ',' === a
            }))
        }
    }
}

function CurrencyConverter(a) {
    var b = function () {
            var a = 0 < arguments.length && arguments[0] !== void 0 ? arguments[0] : '',
                b = arguments[1];
            for (var c in b) a = a.replace('{{' + c + '}}', b[c]);
            return a
        },
        c = function (c, d) {
            return getJSON(b(a.endpoint, {
                from: c,
                to: d
            }), {
                headers: a.headers
            })
        };
    return {
        getExchangeRate: function (d, e) {
            return (isThenable(a.endpoint) ? a.endpoint : c(d, e)).then(function (c) {
                return flattenObject(c)[b(a.propertyPath, {
                    from: d,
                    to: e
                })]
            })
        }
    }
}

function assert(a) {
    var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : new Error;
    if (!a) throw b
}

function assertPercentage(a) {
    assert(isPercentage(a), new RangeError('You must provide a numeric value between 0 and 100.'))
}

function assertValidRatios(a) {
    assert(areValidRatios(a), new TypeError('You must provide a non-empty array of numeric values greater than 0.'))
}

function assertInteger(a) {
    assert(Number.isInteger(a), new TypeError('You must provide an integer.'))
}
var calculator$1 = Calculator(),
    Dinero = function a(b) {
        var c = Math.pow,
            d = Object.assign({}, {
                amount: a.defaultAmount,
                currency: a.defaultCurrency,
                precision: a.defaultPrecision
            }, b),
            e = d.amount,
            f = d.currency,
            g = d.precision;
        assertInteger(e), assertInteger(g);
        var h = a.globalLocale,
            i = a.globalFormat,
            j = a.globalRoundingMode,
            k = a.globalFormatRoundingMode,
            l = Object.assign({}, a.globalExchangeRatesApi),
            m = function (b) {
                var c = Object.assign({}, Object.assign({}, {
                    amount: e,
                    currency: f,
                    precision: g
                }, b), Object.assign({}, {
                    locale: this.locale
                }, b));
                return Object.assign(a({
                    amount: c.amount,
                    currency: c.currency,
                    precision: c.precision
                }), {
                    locale: c.locale
                })
            },
            n = function (a) {
                assert(this.hasSameCurrency(a), new TypeError('You must provide a Dinero instance with the same currency.'))
            };
        return {
            getAmount: function () {
                return e
            },
            getCurrency: function () {
                return f
            },
            getLocale: function () {
                return this.locale || h
            },
            setLocale: function (a) {
                return m.call(this, {
                    locale: a
                })
            },
            getPrecision: function () {
                return g
            },
            convertPrecision: function (a) {
                var b = 1 < arguments.length && void 0 !== arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : k;
                return assertInteger(a), m.call(this, {
                    amount: calculator$1.round(calculator$1.multiply(this.getAmount(), c(10, calculator$1.subtract(a, this.getPrecision()))), b),
                    precision: a
                })
            },
            add: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return m.call(this, {
                    amount: calculator$1.add(c[0].getAmount(), c[1].getAmount()),
                    precision: c[0].getPrecision()
                })
            },
            subtract: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return m.call(this, {
                    amount: calculator$1.subtract(c[0].getAmount(), c[1].getAmount()),
                    precision: c[0].getPrecision()
                })
            },
            multiply: function (a) {
                var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : j;
                return m.call(this, {
                    amount: calculator$1.round(calculator$1.multiply(this.getAmount(), a), b)
                })
            },
            divide: function (a) {
                var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : j;
                return m.call(this, {
                    amount: calculator$1.round(calculator$1.divide(this.getAmount(), a), b)
                })
            },
            percentage: function (a) {
                return assertPercentage(a), this.multiply(calculator$1.divide(a, 100))
            },
            allocate: function (a) {
                var b = this;
                assertValidRatios(a);
                for (var c = a.reduce(function (c, a) {
                        return calculator$1.add(c, a)
                    }), d = this.getAmount(), e = a.map(function (a) {
                        var e = Math.floor(calculator$1.divide(calculator$1.multiply(b.getAmount(), a), c));
                        return d = calculator$1.subtract(d, e), m.call(b, {
                            amount: e
                        })
                    }), f = 0; 0 < d; f++) e[f] = e[f].add(m.call(this, {
                    amount: 1
                })), d = calculator$1.subtract(d, 1);
                return e
            },
            convert: function (a) {
                var b = this,
                    c = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : {},
                    d = c.endpoint,
                    e = d === void 0 ? l.endpoint : d,
                    f = c.propertyPath,
                    g = f === void 0 ? l.propertyPath || 'rates.{{to}}' : f,
                    h = c.headers,
                    i = h === void 0 ? l.headers : h,
                    k = c.roundingMode,
                    n = k === void 0 ? j : k,
                    o = Object.assign({}, {
                        endpoint: e,
                        propertyPath: g,
                        headers: i,
                        roundingMode: n
                    });
                return CurrencyConverter(o).getExchangeRate(this.getCurrency(), a).then(function (c) {
                    return assert(!isUndefined(c), new TypeError('No rate was found for the destination currency "' + a + '".')), m.call(b, {
                        amount: calculator$1.round(calculator$1.multiply(b.getAmount(), parseFloat(c)), o.roundingMode),
                        currency: a
                    })
                })
            },
            equalsTo: function (a) {
                return this.hasSameAmount(a) && this.hasSameCurrency(a)
            },
            lessThan: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return c[0].getAmount() < c[1].getAmount()
            },
            lessThanOrEqual: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return c[0].getAmount() <= c[1].getAmount()
            },
            greaterThan: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return c[0].getAmount() > c[1].getAmount()
            },
            greaterThanOrEqual: function (b) {
                n.call(this, b);
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return c[0].getAmount() >= c[1].getAmount()
            },
            isZero: function () {
                return 0 === this.getAmount()
            },
            isPositive: function () {
                return 0 <= this.getAmount()
            },
            isNegative: function () {
                return 0 > this.getAmount()
            },
            hasSubUnits: function () {
                return 0 !== calculator$1.modulo(this.getAmount(), c(10, g))
            },
            hasCents: function () {
                return 0 !== calculator$1.modulo(this.getAmount(), c(10, g))
            },
            hasSameCurrency: function (a) {
                return this.getCurrency() === a.getCurrency()
            },
            hasSameAmount: function (b) {
                var c = a.normalizePrecision([this, b]);
                return c[0].getAmount() === c[1].getAmount()
            },
            toFormat: function () {
                var a = 0 < arguments.length && arguments[0] !== void 0 ? arguments[0] : i,
                    b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : k,
                    c = Format(a);
                return this.toRoundedUnit(c.getMinimumFractionDigits(), b).toLocaleString(this.getLocale(), {
                    currencyDisplay: c.getCurrencyDisplay(),
                    useGrouping: c.getUseGrouping(),
                    minimumFractionDigits: c.getMinimumFractionDigits(),
                    style: c.getStyle(),
                    currency: this.getCurrency()
                })
            },
            toUnit: function () {
                return calculator$1.divide(this.getAmount(), c(10, g))
            },
            toRoundedUnit: function (a) {
                var b = 1 < arguments.length && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : k,
                    d = c(10, a);
                return calculator$1.divide(calculator$1.round(calculator$1.multiply(this.toUnit(), d), b), d)
            },
            toObject: function () {
                return {
                    amount: e,
                    currency: f,
                    precision: g
                }
            },
            toJSON: function () {
                return this.toObject()
            }
        }
    },
    dinero = Object.assign(Dinero, Defaults, Globals, Static);
```

Comment: Этот код, как я понимаю, вы не сами писали? У автора сей писанины любимая буква `a`, большинство параметров функций и переменные именуются этой буквой. За однобуквенный стиль наименования переменных хочется пробивать в лицо автора сего кода с ноги. А по сути вопроса используйте отладку, вряд ли кто-то будет тратить свое время и захочет делать это за вас.

Comment: Автор сей писанины использовал препроцессор для скриптов, который и переименовал локальные переменные для уменьшения размера.